# How to fix the edge of side bar to stop showing on header in shiny app in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

[image]

There is this weird sort of overlap with header and sidebar and I just want clean lines and borders between the sidebar and header. When the close the sidebar the black part still appears and it shouldn't really.

Here is my code:

```
header =  dashboardHeader(title = HTML("Shiny Seurat"), titleWidth = 140, tags$li(tags$a(href='http://mycompanyishere.com',tags$img(src="https://marcomm.wustl.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1lineposRGB1000-01-23yyr3u-e1517349355451.png", height = "60px", align = "right")), class = "dropdown"))


sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = 150,
                           sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar",
                                       menuItem("Upload", tabName = "Upload", icon = icon("Upload")),
                                       menuItem("Colors", tabName = "Colors", icon = icon("Colors")),
                                       menuItem("PCA", tabName = "PCA", icon = icon("PCA")),
                                       menuItem("TSNE",icon = icon("TSNE"), menuSubItem("TSNE",tabName = "TSNE", icon = icon("TSNE")),
                                                menuSubItem("TSNE-Plot",tabName = "TSNE-Plot", icon = icon("TSNE"))),
                                       menuItem("UMAP", icon = icon("UMAP"), 
                                                menuSubItem("UMAP", tabName = "UMAP", icon = icon("UMAP")),
                                                menuSubItem("Plot", tabName = "Plot", icon = icon("UMAP"))),
                                       menuItem("Expression", tabName = "Expression", icon = icon("Expression")),
                                       menuItem("Differential", tabName = "Differential", icon = icon("Differential"))))
```

Comment: It has definitely something to do with the logo. Anyone has ideas how to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

This would fix it:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
        title = HTML("Shiny Seurat"), 
        titleWidth = 140, 
        tags$li(
            tags$a(
                id = "top-logo",
                href='http://mycompanyishere.com', 
                style = "padding-top: 0",
                tags$img(src="https://marcomm.wustl.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1lineposRGB1000-01-23yyr3u-e1517349355451.png", style = "height: 50px; float:right")
            ), 
            class = "dropdown")
        ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width = 150, sidebarMenu(
            id = "sidebar",
            menuItem("Upload", tabName = "Upload", icon = icon("Upload")),
            menuItem("Colors", tabName = "Colors", icon = icon("Colors")),
            menuItem("PCA", tabName = "PCA", icon = icon("PCA")),
            menuItem("TSNE",icon = icon("TSNE"), menuSubItem("TSNE",tabName = "TSNE", icon = icon("TSNE")),
                     menuSubItem("TSNE-Plot",tabName = "TSNE-Plot", icon = icon("TSNE"))),
            menuItem("UMAP", icon = icon("UMAP"), 
                     menuSubItem("UMAP", tabName = "UMAP", icon = icon("UMAP")),
                     menuSubItem("Plot", tabName = "Plot", icon = icon("UMAP"))),
            menuItem("Expression", tabName = "Expression", icon = icon("Expression")),
            menuItem("Differential", tabName = "Differential", icon = icon("Differential"))
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$style(
            "
            #top-logo:hover {background: rgb(60 141 188)}
            "
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]